# twitter and facebook app in a modal div inside an iframe

Tags: facebook, twitter

I need to link the user's twitter and facebook profiles in a website profile while the website is loaded inside other websites' through iframe.
Is it possible to do that using a modal div inside that iframe? I'm quite in trouble thinking about the return url and page reload.
Have some example?
btw i'm using php but think it's not important now
Thanks,
A.

Comment: What do you mean by linking the users' profiles?

Comment: I mean to let the user login and let the website know which are the Twitter and FB account of the user (something like  Klout does)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what ever you want in your page even when it resides in an iframe. What you can do in it (visually) is only limited by the dimensions of the iframe (unless the hosting page has some kind of layer on top of your iframe).

I can't speak of the twitter way of doing things (you can always check their [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs)) but with facebook it's pretty easy to integrate into the graph using the [api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).
You need to have a facebook app, and then in your page (even if it's in an iframe) you can use the [javascript sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) to [authenticate](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) the user and then use the graph as you need (and have [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) to).